# how to provide a parameter for interactive lamda function

Tags: key-bindings, helm, interactive

I want to be able to perform `helm-swoop` on an input `error:` on a compiler output buffer using `C-x C-r`, here is how I tried to achieve it.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-r") (lambda () (interactive) (helm-swoop "error:")))
```

When I try to use it I get:

```
Keyword argument error: not one of (:$query :$source :$multiline)
```

I'm in a process of learning Emacs Lisp. Having this short cut would help speed up a workflow looking up compiler errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(lambda () (interactive) ...)` syntax is just fine.  The problem you are encountering is with your invocation of `helm-swoop`.  The arguments for that function must be keyed (preceded by their argument `:keyword`).  `C-h f` shows that the signature is:

```
(helm-swoop &key $QUERY $SOURCE ($MULTILINE current-prefix-arg))
```

Try this:

```
(lambda (query)
  (interactive "sQuery: ")
  (helm-swoop :$query "error:"))
```

As @Tobias mentions, `helm-swoop` employs keyword arguments because it is defined by `cl-defun`.  The `cl-defun` help page has a link to the `cl` info page ["Argument Lists"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Argument-Lists.html) which describes `&key` in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, you just made my day! Plain and simple answer. On the follow up: Is :$query a part of a language? I assume it is, but not sure.

Comment: Keywords are are self- quoting symbols that start with a ":" (so you don't need to use a "'" at the beginning).  They are used for various things like denoting named/labeled arguments like that function.  It occurred to me that you wanted to read user input.  Try `(lambda (query) (interactive "sQuery: ") ... )`

Comment: Maybe mention that `helm-swoop` is defined by `cl-defun`. The help for `cl-defun` has a link to the cl info page for "keyword" arguments.